# How do I read an JSON object in python?

Tags: python, json

Im currently working on a Python Pygame project were I have to work with JSON files. Im trying to read of an JSON file but I just cant get it to print what I want to know.

Here is the JSON file

```
  "pokemons": {
    "5": {
      "name": "Snivy",
      "type": "Grass",
      "hp": 45,
      "attack": 45,
      "defence": 55,
      "speed": 63,
      "moves": [
        "Tackle",
        "Leer",
        "null",
        "null"
      ],
      "level": 4,
      "xp": 54
    },
    "2": {
      "name": "Tepig",
      "type": "Fire",
      "hp": 65,
      "attack": 63,
      "defence": 45,
      "speed": 45,
      "moves": [
        "Tackle",
        "Tail Whip",
        "Ember",
        "null"
      ],
      "level": 7,
      "xp": 11
    }
  }
}
```

Im trying to read the "name", "type", ect from the different "ID's" aka "5" and "2", but I can only make it print "5" and "2" from the "pokemons" array

```
with open("data.json", "r") as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    for i in data["pokemons"]:
        print(i)
```

Comment: Iterate a dictionary as `for k,v in data['pokemonds'].items(): print (k, v)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've titled this `json read from array inside of array python`, but you don't have JSON arrays (translated into Python lists) here - you have JSON objects (translated into Python dicts).

```
for i in data["pokemons"]:
```

`data["pokemons"]` is a dict, so iterating over it like this gives you the keys - `"5"` and "2"`. You can use those to index into the data:

```
data["pokemons"][i]
```

That gives you one of the objects (dicts) representing an individual pokemon, from which you can access the name:

```
data["pokemons"][i]["name"]
```

Better yet, you can loop over the values of `data["pokemons"]` directly, instead of the keys:

```
for pokemon in data["pokemons"].values():
    name = pokemon["name"]
```

Or you can get both at once using `.items()`, for example:

```
for pid, pokemon in data["pokemons"].items():
    # use string formatting to display the pid and matching name together.
    print(f"pokemon number {pid} has name {pokemon['name']}")
```

Comment: Thank you so much, im sorry for the wrong title, will change that. I have not worked that much with JSON files before so im realy happy for the help, thanks again!

Comment: It's not really a question of "working with JSON files" - once you have made the `.load` call, it's ordinary Python data. But sometimes this is someone's first time dealing with deeply nested structures, I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

My Solution

```
data = '{"pokemons": {"5": {"name": "Snivy","type": "Grass","hp": 45,"attack": 45,"defence": 55,"speed": 63,"moves": ["Tackle","Leer","null","null"],"level": 4,"xp": 54},"2": {"name": "Tepig","type": "Fire","hp": 65,"attack": 63,"defence": 45,"speed": 45,"moves": ["Tackle","Tail Whip","Ember","null"],"level": 7,"xp": 11}}}}'
datadict = json.loads(data)
dataOfId = datadict['pokemons']
for i in dataOfId:
      print(dataOfId[i]["name"])
      print(dataOfId[i]["type"])
```